# On an inequality relating to nonnegative convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability, convex-analysis

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent, continuous integrable random variables and $\varphi$ is a nonnegative convex function.

How do I prove the statement: $E[\varphi(X+Y)] \geq E[\varphi(X+EY)]$, where $EX$ is the expected value of $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in my comment

$$E[\phi(X+Y)]=E\big[E[\phi(X+Y)|\sigma(X)]\big]$$
Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $E\big[E[\phi(X+Y)|\sigma(X)]\big]=h(X)$
where $h(x)=E[\phi(x+Y)]$. For any $x$ fixed, the function $\phi_x(y)=\phi(x+y)$ is convex:
$$\phi_x(\alpha y_1+(1-\alpha)y_2)=\phi(\alpha(x+y_1)+(1-\alpha)(x+y_2))\leq\alpha\phi_x(y_1)+(1-\alpha)\phi_x(y_2)$$
Hence$$h(x)=E[\phi(x+Y)]=E[\phi_x(Y)]\geq \phi_x(E[Y])=\phi(x+E[Y])$$
Therefore $$E[\phi(X+Y)]=E[h(X)]\geq E[\phi(X+E[Y])]$$

Comment: I think there is a typo in line 3 of your solution. $h(X) = E[\phi(X+Y)|\sigma(X)]$.

Answer (score 1):

First let's show that $$E[\varphi(X+Y)\mid X]\geq \varphi(X+EY)$$
In fact, for $X=x$, let's $f(y)=\varphi(x+y)$ which is convex as $\phi$ is convex. Using Jensen Inequality, we get $$E[f(Y)]\geq f(EY) \Rightarrow E[\varphi(x+Y)]\geq \varphi(x+EY)$$
Now,
$$E[E[\varphi(X+Y)\mid X=x]] \geq E[\varphi(X+EY)\mid X=x]$$
$$E[\varphi(X+Y)] = E[E[\varphi(X+Y)\mid X=x]] \geq E[E[\varphi(X+EY)\mid X=x]] = E[\varphi(X+EY)]$$